# Determine if a page has been saved yet and has an ID using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a metabox on the edit screen which will check a custom database table for existance of a record matching the current pages ID.  If the record exist then I show all my data.  If the record does not exist yet then I instead show a button **Create A/B Test**

My problem is that I must query my custom DB table using the page ID.  When you create a new page, before saving the page there is no ID created yet.

So before the page is saved and I have access to an ID, I do not want to show my **Create A/B Test** button as it will also require me to have access to a page ID.

So how can I detect that the page has not been saved and does not yet have an ID?  If I can detect this, then I can instead show a message to save the page 1st or something before giving access to create AB test DB records.

I can't think of a clever solution so I am hoping someone might have some ideas?

If I can determine that the page is un-saved I could possibly have a button in my meta box which can be clicked to save the page and then reveal my content.

Comment: How about `if( ! get_post( $post->ID ) )` in the metabox content?

Comment: *"When you create a new page, before saving the page there is no ID created yet"*. Note that when you click "Add new page"  the page is saved to the db with an ID and status *auto-draft*.

Comment: @birgire I just checked DB to confirm that the ID doesnt change once saved or published and it doesn't so this is what I needed thanks!